# Finding limits of integration for volume integral

Tags: integration

Compute the volume of solid enclosed between the surfaces $x^2+y^2=9$ and $x^2+z^2=9$

What should be the limits of the integrals ?

I am getting this

z  from $-\sqrt{9-x^2}$to $\sqrt{9-x^2}$

x from $-\sqrt{9-y^2}$ to $ \sqrt{9-y^2}$

y from $0$ to $3$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of any region $W$ can be found using triple integrals as follows:

$$V=\iiint_WdV$$

Your boundaries are almost correct. However you are limiting $y$ to the positive $y$ axis, which is only a half-sphere. The interval for $y$ should be $-3\le{y}\le{3}$.

Comment: I know this far, i am unable to determine the limits of integration

Comment: @AmanMittal See my latest edit.

Comment: Ok, That makes sense. Thats all i wanted. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6):

As you noted, you are looking for a triple integration, but I am posting another parallel approach. If we consider the whole volume, we have $8$ times of the following solid thing(right on the top). This means that, I consider the first $1/8$ of $\mathbb R^3$ for working. And, I am assuming you can find out why the thin slab is really an square (Just examine the equations of both Cylinder). Moreover, we can move that piece from $x=0..x=3$ and so:

$$V_{1/8}=\int_0^3S_{\small{\text{slab}}}(x)dx=\int_0^3(9-x^2)dx$$

I think this way is easier than doing triple integrals, however, you may not like it. So just keep it for the later and let's wait for your desire solution.  :-)

[image]

Comment: That is an excellent diagram in any case !!

Comment: @AmanMittal: Thanks! :-)

Comment: @BabakS. You're an artist.

Comment: Artist, indeed, Babak! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy, Thanks Git. You can see the trace of the pencil there. I love this way of teaching.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks for your nice words.

Comment: @BabakS.: I agree, what a beautiful illustration of the problem! +1